# Count Instances in One Array Based on Another Array

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to perform the following. I have two (numpy) arrays, and I would like to count the number of instances of a value occurring in one based on the criteria of another another array. For example:

```
a = np.array([1,-1,1,1,-1,-1])
b = np.array([.75,.35,.7,.8,.2,.6])
```

I would like to calculate `c` as the number of 1's in `a` that occur when `b` > .5, so in this case `c = 3'. My current solution is ugly and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.sum` for this:

```
a = np.array([1,-1,1,1,-1,-1])
b = np.array([.75,.35,.7,.8,.2,.6])

np.sum((a == 1) & (b > .5))  # 3
```

This works because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one condition you are after, try:

`np.count_nonzero((a == 1) & (b > .5))`

Comment: Or if the desired answer is 3 then `np.count_nonzero`?

Comment: `np.count_nonzero((a == 1) & (b > .5))` is what I was looking for. Thanks @Da

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the correction, have updated my answer.